# get route parameters in angular with lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would retrieve a parameter from my route path in Angular 5

```
http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/74618/LastCC
```

I would get  `74618` from route which is an `id` parameter.

I have processed like this

```
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)


this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log("params******");
  params.get("id");
});
```

I get `undefined` as value.

It's working when I'm on this path `http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard/74618/`  (Without `\LastCC` )

LastCC is lazy Loaded and here's the router config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: CreditPointComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CreditPointRoutingModule {}
```

The id parameter is on the parent module router configuration ( Dashboard module ).

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ":id",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "LastCC",
        loadChildren:
          "app/useful-documents/credit-point/credit-point.module#CreditPointModule"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Comment: What does your router configuration look like?

Comment: Provide your routing module code where you have configured the routes.

Comment: I have added new informations

Comment: There are no parameters in your route

Comment: I have added the parent module routes

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a parameter configured on the `LastCC` route. Try something like this:

```
  {
    path: ":id",
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
     path: ":id/LastCC",
     loadChildren:
          "app/useful-documents/credit-point/credit-point.module#CreditPointModule"
   }
```

Notice that the path for the LastCC route now has a route parameter: `path: ":id/LastCC"`

Notice also that the LastCC route is no longer a child route. Did it need to be?

If it *does* need to be a child route, then you may need to leave the route configuration as you have it and read the parameter from the parent's route instead of from the `LastCC` route.

```
this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log("params******");
  console.log(params.get("id"));
});
```

Notice the `.parent` after the `activatedRoute`.

Comment: I should read it from the parent yes. Is your second solution works on angular 5 ?

Comment: Yes. Routing has not changed much since Angular 4.